# Login screen remains on lightdm, while desktop on GNOME Xorg

Tags: unity, gnome, 17.10, lock-screen, wayland

After running Ubuntu 17.04, my computer prompted me with the 17.10, which I accepted. I heard that 17.04 uses Wayland by default, but now I updated, I only have the Xorg option.

And for some reason, I still have the Lightdm login screen even if my desktop is the GNOME one and I chose gdm by default when prompted during the update.

How can I recover Wayland and change the login screen for the GNOME one ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The login screen is either Lightdm or gdm and cannot be Unity. When you log in, what options are you given? On my system I have Ubuntu or Ubuntu on Xorg. the Ubuntu choice is for Wayland and the other is, oviously Xorg. Once Ubuntu is running you can check whether it is using Wayland or Xorg by running "echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE"

Comment: My bad, the login screen is Lightdm. When I log in I have two options : Ubuntu and Ubuntu with Xorg, but when I try to click on Ubuntu, it chooses Ubuntu with Xorg anyway. Also, when running "echo..." I get X11.

Comment: Try switching from LightDM to gdm. To do that open a terminal and type "sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm" then select gdm and reboot.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it fixed both problems in one go ! When I used the command you gave me, I got an error message telling me that gdm was not active. So I used "sudo gdm3", then it brought me to the gdm login screen. I entered my password but it was stuck on a loop on the login screen, so I restarted the computer and it worked, and for some reason I can choose between Wayland and Xorg too now. Thanks again, you've been really helpful !

Comment: By the way, if you want to use the Answer button, I would be very glad to validate it :)

Comment: I did but you didn't!

Comment: My bad, didn't get the notification about the answer :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad to have been of help. Here's the solution as an answer rather than a comment:

Switch from LightDM to gdm. To do that open a terminal and type

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm

then select gdm and reboot.